# Is it possible to use a mic and speaker connected to a phone or computer to do noise cancelling?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, speakers, noise

I am working from home and there are plenty of distractions, from neighbours dog to their children. I want to reduce using in-ear earphone that is the only thing effective to give me some quiet for working. I know that noise cancellation works by outputting ambient noise and causing destructive interference of sound.

Since the phones and laptops come with both mic and speaker I want to generate a run a noise-cancelling wave from the speakers. Is there a software that can do this? Also if its runs on ubuntu that would be great.

Comment: Found detailed discussion already happening here https://superuser.com/questions/61865/does-this-exist-software-for-noise-cancellation

Comment: Yes. "Playback of latency-corrected, phase-inverted background noise together with the usable signal. This works rather well for headphones, although it does usually introduce some smearing in the basses. However, this, too, does not work offline as it needs the actual background noise signal from the surroundings. And it is not very usable for PCs since they introduce too much audio latency" reinforces what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Delays in the digital processing of the audio inputs and in generating the inverse waveform will result in imperfect cancellation as noted in https://superuser.com/a/72557/264083. Suggest you instead get noise cancelling headphones or earbuds, where the noise cancellation runs in the headphone's hardware, and is not delayed by what else is going on in your PC.